# Не загружаются некоторые PDF файлы на сервер через веб форму

Tags: php, yii, yii2, iis, iis-7

Win2008 + IIS 7.5 + PHP 5.6 + Yii 2.0.5

На сайте есть форма загрузки файлов.

Файлы прекрасно загружаются, кроме некоторых PDF файлов. Это значит, что некоторые PDF файлы, которые абсолютно нормально открываются в любом просмотрщике, не хотят загружаться на сайт, если посмотреть массив $_FILES, то для таких файлов там будет только имя файла, для всех других файлов, в том числе и других PDF, $_FILES содержит всю необходимую информацию.
Если такие PDF файлы пересохранить в любом PDF редакторе, то они начинают загружаться.

Сделали простейшую страничку для загрузки файлов, минимум кода - история повторяется, т.е. дело точно не в YII.

Перепробовали разные варианты, исходили гугл и мануалы, причину найти не можем.

В чем может быть дело, куда копать?

Comment: Встречал сообщение о том, что какой-то сервак неадекватно реагировал на слишком длинную последовательность нулевых байтов. Напишите самый простой обработчик на любом другом языке, посмотрите, будет ли что-нибудь приходить, и если там тоже будет аналогичная ситуация - дело в IIS.

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть настройки сервера, например размер загружаемого файла, размер через HTTP протокол и т.д.